# Disable time and AM/PM in UIdatepicker

Tags: iphone

how to Disable time and AM/PM column in UIdatepicker...

Answer (score 4):

```
[myUiDatePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use "Countdown Timer" datePickerMode:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
```

However note that it will also add "hours" and "minutes" after hours and minutes numbers respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];

[self.datePicker setLocale:locale];
```