# Is it possible to lock Time in UIDatePicker but the date is still selectable?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

What I want to do is to lock the spinner or the time column in a UIDatepicker? But you can still select a date.

I don't want a default of 00:00, or just to concat the date. Currently what I'm doing is

Example:

- I have a UITextField with a date 10/20/2013 08:00
- Then if the user tap the UITextField, Im doing two different formatter to get the time, and the date only.
- Store the time to a variable, then after the user finished selecting the date, I then concat the time back to current user choice.
- Then display it back to the UITextField

I think this method is not the most optimize choice. Does anyone have any suggestion? I do need to lock the time for a reason.

Thanks in advance :3

EDIT: 
Some of you didn't understand my question.. I want to have date and time picker but the time column cannot be changed but there would be default time... so the date picker would have 05-04-2013 12:00 the 12:00 is still showing but not editable

EDIT:
Wow, I didn't know that If you comment on an answer that tells them that there response is wrong, they would take it personally and down vote your question.

Comment: why not just use only the date picker? why even show a control that's normally used to pick date and time and disable half the wheels? Don't you think people will immediately try to adjust the time? And when they do don't you think it will be frustrating and confusing when things don't work as expected? I suggest you change course and rethink your UI.

Comment: - No, -Because I need to, - No. As I said i have a reason for it, and explaining it would be tedious. So I just ask my problem to its simplest form. In accordance to UI, that has been discussed already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIDatePickerModeDate` or you can use combination of `UIDatePickerModeDate` and `UIDatePickerModeTime`;

Comment: you guyz did not understand the question.. I want to have date and time picker but the time column cannot be changed but there would be default time... so the date picker would have 05-04-2013 12:00 the 12:00 is still showing but not editable

Comment: i am saying that to use custom view for this, like date picker and exact copy of time fild...

Comment: Yeh this might be another solution. Making a Custom UIView with a date picker  with a time field. But the problem now is concatenating it to a single  string. I guess it is the same as my solution above, putting it to another variable then just concat it to the date that the user chose. Thanks, unike the other guy who downvote me because he can't take that his answer is wrong.

Comment: @AndrewJamesRamirez -> Other guys are watching this as a nonsense question, and i always take questions as a challenge... any way +1 for u :)

Answer (score 0):

try this way......

**Change the mode of date picker....**

```
date_pic.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
```

**Update**

> you can't achieve this by DatePicker which display the Time & Date.
>   Either you can just show the dates in DatePicker.

**Also See this**

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803345/disable-time-and-am-pm-in-uidatepicker)

Comment: Is this helpful to yo?

Comment: No, sorry, I already know that, try reading my question again, my goal is to show date and time, but the time cannot be edit/adjust.

Comment: Disable is not the same as removing.

Comment: yes, I know that but Apple is not provide the thing which you are searching.

Comment: yeh That's why I'm asking if its possible or any other solution to the current solution that I have. But your answer didn't answer any of that. So why downvote me.